# Where are method reference copies stored in java?

Tags: java, memory

When you invoke a method with a passed field, a copy of this field's value in stack is created. This means if it is a primitive type, by changing the value of this variable, you will not change the value of the passed field. However if you change a value in heap, the reference will be a copy, but still reference the same memory, meaning you can the value of the passed field.

My question is where are these temporary variables stored? if they are references they should be stored in stack correct? but stack has static memory allocation and if methods are invoked when the code is running, they must be stored in dynamically allocated memory correct? So it is a contradiction.

Sorry if this questions sounds dumb, I am a novice programmer, and am trying to understand properly how programs work with memory.

Comment: "*I am a novice programmer, and am trying to understand properly how programs work with memory*" My advice would be: don't spend your (finite) effort in trying to understand it. Not yet anyway. Java does what it can to deliberately abstract away the exact details of how memory is managed. Understanding it will not help you, not as a novice.

Comment: 'Stack has static memory allocation' is the only contradiction here. Elements are pushed onto and popped from the stack dynamically. It is the same for references as for primitives. Don't overcomplicate this.

Comment: Don't make personal remarks here. I'm trying to help you. I don't need your advice.

Answer (score 1):

> ... but stack has static memory allocation and if methods are invoked when the code is running, they must be stored in dynamically allocated memory correct?

Incorrect.  Allocation on the stack is not static.  It is dynamic.  Stack frames are added when a method is called, and removed when the method call exits.

All local variables are held in the stack frame of the respective method call on a thread's stack.  This us true whether the variable has a primitive type or a reference type.

---

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "method reference copies".

Java 8 and later have support for things called "method references", so I'm not sure if you are talking about those or about a method's local variables that have a reference type.

If you are talking about "method references", then the answer is that these are reference types, and are represented like other reference type.  There is a reference (a pointer) which points to a node in the heap which holds the state of the "method reference".  The reference (pointer) can be held in a local variable on the stack, in a static variable, or in a field / element of some other heap-resident object.

---

Finally:

> I am a novice programmer, and am trying to understand properly how programs work with memory.

My advice would be don't.  You don't need to understand how Java programs "work with memory" to be an effective and proficient Java programmer.  The Java runtime system deals with all of that stuff ... so that you *don't* need to understand it.

My advice would be:

1. Wait until you are an experienced Java programmer.
2. Wait until you have done degree level courses on both computer hardware architectures AND compiler writing.
3. Wait until you **need** to understand this.